# vb.net combobox connected with another combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

so i need help in this following code:

```
 Private Sub cbxkelas_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbxkelas.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        Dim kel As String
        kel = cbxkelas.SelectedText.FirstOrDefault()
        If kel = "2" Or "4" Or "6" Then
            cbxsemes.SelectedItem = "Genap"
        Else
            cbxsemes.SelectedItem = "Ganjil"
        End If
        cbxsemes.Items.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

im trying to get a cbxsemex(combobox) value depending on the choice made at cbxkelas(combobox) first character but when i choose "1psi2" at cbxkelas it still show "Genap" in cbxsemes.

Comment: Could you explain why you clear the content of cbxsemes?

Comment: i need to make it clean so when the previous combobox (cbxkelas) selected it change automatically

Comment: Perhaps you should clear and refill the cbxsemes only when the cbxkelas changes its selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) set to OFF.
This settings allows a syntax like the one in this line

```
 If kel = "2" Or "4" Or "6" Then
```

to pass through but in your context it makes no sense because the line is evaluated as

```
 If (kel = "2") Or ("4" Or "6") Then
```

and, with Option Strict set to OFF, an automatic conversion from the strings "4" and "6" to booleans happens. Of course this conversion gives back true as result (if the string was "0" you will get false)

You code should be

```
 If kel = "2" Or kel = "4" Or kel = "6" Then
```

So, my recommendation is to change Option Strict to ON. Probably, after this,  your program will fail to compile correctly but it will also highlight a lot of other places where you should look carefully if you are really getting the result expected.

Still it is not clear why you remove all items from the same combobox that you have just set the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

your condition must change to

```
If kel = "2" Or kel = "4" Or kel = "6" Then
```

Comment: A string is just an array of chars. FirstOrDefault can work albeit it is a bit excessive to use it when you could simply get the first char using the normal array indexer (cbxkelas.SelectedText(0))